# html5 - How do I link my pages to the section from my nav > Id (navhome >#home)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm re-designing a site to make it more mobile friendly. I've re-structured the whole site but can't get the main pages to show up. The logo, nav, asides and a mock img shows in the main section. I'm trying to not use iframes. I can't seem to get the nav to point to the local or internal pages I've re-created. I've tried researching this and can't find anything that will work. It's probably something simple but I can't seem to find the problem. PLEASE HELP...THX in advance.

```js
// JavaScript Document

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "90px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 background-image:url(lines.png);
}
#wrapper {
 width:95%;
 min-width:340px;
 max-width:1100px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#ffffff;
 background-color:#000000;
 border-color:#ffffff;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
 position:inherit;
 }
h1 {
  font: inherit;
}
header {
 margin:0 auto;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:6;
}
.logo {
 width:100%;
 max-width: 313px;
 height: auto; 
 padding: 10px;
}
nav {
 right:0;
 text-align:right;
 padding: 33px 10px 20px 10px;
 background-color: #4C6972;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
 position:relative;
 z-index:5;
}
 .menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size:13px;
 font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 color: #f1f1f1;  
 padding:0 5px 0 10px;
}
.menu a:hover {
 color: #111; 
} 
span {
 color: #54d17a;
}
.hambtn, .closebtn {
 display:none;
}
main {
 height:100%;
 position:relative;
 z-index:3;
}
aside {
 margin:0 auto;
 top: 75px;
 left:0px;
 width:15%;
 font-size: 18px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:4;
}
/*top right bottom left*/
.icon-bar {
 float:left;
 clear:left;
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding:5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
}
.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

section {
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 position:inherit;
 z-index:3;
 display:block;
}
#home{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 background:url(../home.html) no-repeat;
}
#music{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 background:url(../music.html) no-repeat;
}
footer {
 text-align: center;
 font-size:9px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding: 10px;
 z-index:6;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>7-2stackoverflow</title>
<link href="css/7-2stackoverflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/7-2indiwirenavcol.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

      <header>xxxxxxx</header>

 <nav>
   <div class="hambtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</div>
  <div id="sidenav" class="menu">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
   <a href="#home">home</a>
   <a href="#music">music</a>
   <a href="#about">about</a>
   <a href="#gigs">gigs</a>
   <a href="#contact"><span>contact</span></a>
  </div>
  </nav>
 <main>
   <aside>
  <div class="icon-bar">
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       
  </div>
   </aside>

       <section>
<div id="home"><!--one youtube vid goes here--></div>
<div id="music"><!--music player html goes here--></div>
<div id="about"><!--about html goes here--></div>
<div id="gigs"><!--gigs html goes here--></div>
<div id="contact"><!--contact form html goes here--></div>
 </section>

   <footer>&reg;&copy; xxxxxx 2001-2019  All rights reserved</footer>   
 </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Both your hamburger menu and close button are hidden by default -- there's nothing for you to click on. Unhiding these elements shows your JavaScript working as expected.

Comment: Hi, Your question is not clear.

Comment: sorry, I'm a newby here. I can't seem to get the nav home...etc to show the local page which should show in the section part of the html. nav-->home should show up in section --> home div(home.html) I hope that is clearer.

Comment: i didn't see the first comment...the hamburg isn't the issue...it works fine on my end. when I uploaded here I must have accidently deleted something. But that isn't the issue. I can't get the home.html, music.html..etc to show up when I click it. If I put a random image in the section it shows...but that seems to be all I can show. Even if I put a direct link (<a href="home.html" target="_self" id="home">) in the section it won't show up???

Comment: i've now done    <a href="#home" onclick="mySections()">home</a>
// JavaScript Document
function mySections() {
  document.getElementById("home.html").innerHTML = "home.html";
  document.getElementById("music").innerHTML = "music.html";
}
still nothing...

Comment: Are you just trying to get the links to scroll you to the section they correspond to? Because that is working just fine in your example. You just have to put some content  into those divs so that the page has something to scroll to

Comment: at this point scrolling would be fine. The section part has 5 html docs that won't show up.

Comment: there is a
home.html
music.html
about.html
gigs.html
contact.html
all in divs in the section part of the main html

Comment: <section>
<div id="home"><a href="home.html"></a></div>
</section>
doesn't show up at all

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine. Here is the below snippet.You need to fill your `div` with videos, music etc. Below is the working snippet

```js
// JavaScript Document

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "90px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("sidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
 margin:0 0 0 0;
 background-image:url(lines.png);
}
#wrapper {
 width:95%;
 min-width:340px;
 max-width:1100px;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#ffffff;
 background-color:#000000;
 border-color:#ffffff;
 border-style:solid;
 border-width:0 1px 1px 1px;
 position:inherit;
 }
h1 {
  font: inherit;
}
header {
 margin:0 auto;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:6;
}
.logo {
 width:100%;
 max-width: 313px;
 height: auto; 
 padding: 10px;
}
nav {
 right:0;
 text-align:right;
 padding: 33px 10px 20px 10px;
 background-color: #4C6972;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
 position:relative;
 z-index:5;
}
 .menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size:13px;
 font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 color: #f1f1f1;  
 padding:0 5px 0 10px;
}
.menu a:hover {
 color: #111; 
} 
span {
 color: #54d17a;
}
.hambtn, .closebtn {
 display:none;
}
main {
 height:100%;
 position:relative;
 z-index:3;
}
aside {
 margin:0 auto;
 top: 75px;
 left:0px;
 width:15%;
 font-size: 18px;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:4;
}
/*top right bottom left*/
.icon-bar {
 float:left;
 clear:left;
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding:5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
}
.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

section {
 width:100%;
 height: 100%;
 position:inherit;
 z-index:3;
 display:block;
}
#home{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 background:url(../home.html) no-repeat red;
  height:100vh
}
#music{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 background:url(../music.html) no-repeat yellow;
   height:100vh
}
footer {
 text-align: center;
 font-size:9px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding: 10px;
 z-index:6;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>7-2stackoverflow</title>
<link href="css/7-2stackoverflow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/7-2indiwirenavcol.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

      <header>xxxxxxx</header>

 <nav>
   <div class="hambtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</div>
  <div id="sidenav" class="menu">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
   <a href="#home">home</a>
   <a href="#music">music</a>
   <a href="#about">about</a>
   <a href="#gigs">gigs</a>
   <a href="#contact"><span>contact</span></a>
  </div>
  </nav>
 <main>
   <aside>
  <div class="icon-bar">
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX       
  </div>
   </aside>

       <section>
<div id="home"><!--one youtube vid goes here--> home</div>
<div id="music"><!--music player html goes here-->music</div>
<div id="about"><!--about html goes here-->about</div>
<div id="gigs"><!--gigs html goes here-->gigs</div>
<div id="contact"><!--contact form html goes here-->contact</div>
 </section>

   <footer>&reg;&copy; xxxxxx 2001-2019  All rights reserved</footer>   
 </main>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To load `abc.html` in your home page, you can use jQuery as follow. Make sure that you have added jQuery CDN

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#about').load('about.html');
  $('#gigs').load('gigs.html');
  $('#contact').load('contact.html'); 
 })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sai Manoj, it's a start. it shows the section of home and music at least but does not show the actual home.html or music.html. also the other navs don't show up in the section at all. I'm don't really know how to write js yet but i've been looking for snippets to add to maybe load the htmls? any suggestion would be much appreciated as I've had no luck so far.

Comment: I really didn't understand what's your problem. Do you wanna scroll to the div as per your nav list or do you wanna navigate to other page ?

Comment: If you want I can help you using jQuery.Updated the answer with jquery to show your HTML inside the div

Comment: I added the updated jquery snippet but the pages still won't show...I had already added in the head tag <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>. Is that the jQuery CDN you were referring to?

Comment: thanks so much Sai Manoj...it turns out it just wasn't working on my local browser for some reason. I uploaded it to a test attached to the present sites server and it works. Now I have to just redo sizes and things to make it resize for mobile....again thanks a bunch...it's been an issue for like 3 weeks....phew...now I can move forward

Comment: @mim you should run live reload to run that on your local system. Please accept my answer if you feel that it was helpful. Happy coding :)